# Authenticate users by a URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am quiet confused about how to find the technical solution of my business need. I just want to be able to give third party web apps a temporary URL to a specific user so he can access his account without log in.

I have though about a certificate that  I use for every external portal. So When I get a request from them with a specific address I send them a redirect URL that is available for 5 minutes.

My application is build over .NET MVC.
Could somebody help me find out how to implement this need ?

Comment: Which type of user authentication are you using?

Comment: While sending URL to third party encrypt uid ,token and timestamp and pass as querystring. Also in background map these 3 properties. Whenever user hits url with encrypted querystring, compare hash,expiry of link with yours and allow access.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a token and set an expiry date and send the token as query parameter and create an authorization attribute class to check if you have the token and it is valid or any other authorization you have.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to do it but you can begin with [Basic Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775(v=vs.110).aspx) which I ended up implementing. I advice you to read the whole tutorial, any misleading could end you up to a non working code with lots of headaches.
If you need more powerful security you can go for [Certificate Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731074(v=vs.110).aspx) where you have to provide your clients with client certificates.
These [link1](http://southworks.com/blog/2014/06/16/enabling-ssl-client-certificates-in-asp-net-web-api/), [link2](http://www.developerhandbook.com/wcf/easy-wcf-security-authorization-users/), could be useful too if you don't have experience dealing with certificate generation and implementation.